# Does the Logitech F710 work on the PS2?

Tags: controllers, ps2

I have seen from various web sales, [such as this one](https://www.flipkart.com/logitech-wireless-gamepad-f710/p/itmdyfyf8vzdejhh?pid=ACCDYFXZYZ9WZPNN&lid=LSTACCDYFXZYZ9WZPNNZRWQYP&marketplace=FLIPKART&fm=organic&iid=95c499b4-6baf-4d30-8a55-6b610217abdd.ACCDYFXZYZ9WZPNN.PRODUCTSUMMARY&ppt=pp&ppn=pp&ssid=dlchlf74yo0000001583493008635), that the Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710 is advertised as working for PS3, PC, and PS2.

Despite it being advertised as PS2 compatible, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Does anyone know if it works on the PS2 at all, or how I can make it work if it does?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What have you tried? What happens? What do web sales have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manufacturer's product page on their site](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gamepads/f710-wireless-gamepad.html#product-tech-specs), it is officially supported for Windows 8, 7, and Vista. Also according to the site, it also works with Android TV based systems.

It uses XInput or DirectInput, meaning it is compatible with both games that expect a Xbox Gamepad (Xbox 360 or Xbox One style, interchangeably) or a traditional DirectInput controller (mostly older games, flight sims, things that in general don't expect a modern gamepad).

Anecdotally, any controller I've used that supports XInput and/or DirectInput works perfectly well on Windows 10 too, that's what the standards are for.

EDIT: Note there do seem to be people on the internet who have gotten 360 style controllers (XInput) to work on different hardware than PC or Xbox, but I don't see a quick and easy adapter to be bought.